# How to list ftp directories by using FtpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I need list ftp site directory with username and password, and I can access it in FileZilla.

The Directory structure in FileZilla is like below,

/
FtpDir
  Input
    Input
    Archive
  Output
    Output
    Archive

However, when accessing it in FtpWebRequest class in C#, it gives exception "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)". The code is,

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.xx.x.xx.xx/FtpDir/Input/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

I have accessed another Ftp site successfully, the uri is like ftp://ftp.somecompany.com/FtpDir/
and I can access ftp://ftp.somecompany.com/FtpDir/ from file explorer as well.
But I cannot access ftp://ftp.xx.x.xx.xx/FtpDir/Input/ from file explorer.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

request.UsePassive = false; solved the problem.